# Create .txt using Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, forms, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to create a `.txt` using JavaScript this worked:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("form").each(function() {
                $(this)
})

  var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'); // document.querySelector => Get the first element in the document with tag textarea
  var anchor = document.querySelector('a');

  anchor.onclick = function() {
                anchor.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(textarea.value);
                anchor.download = 'export.txt';
  };
</script>
        <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
        <form>

            Name: <input type="text" name="name">
            <br><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
            <br><br>
            Web: <input type="text" name="website">
            <br><br>
            Kom: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
            <br><br>
            G:
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="w">w
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">m
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <textarea></textarea>
            <p><a href="#">Export</a></p>
</form>
```

Browser downloads a .txt file with the data the user put into the field.

But if I try to do something like this, the downloaded .txt file shows unknown as a result.

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var anchor = document.querySelector('a');
            
anchor.onclick = function() {
       anchor.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(input.value);
       anchor.download = 'export.txt';
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
    <br><br>
    Web: <input type="text" name="website">
   <br><br>
   Kom: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
   <br><br>
   G:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="w">w
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">m
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <p><a href="#">Export</a></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` because you specify what type of `input` you want to loop over. `getElementsByTagName()` return all inputs including submit button, and it returns an array, so you need to loop over it.

```js
var inputs = $("input[type=text], textarea");
var anchor = document.querySelector('a');

anchor.onclick = function() {

       var content = '';
       inputs.each(function(){
         content += ' '+ $(this).val();
       });
  
       anchor.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(content);
       anchor.download = 'export.txt';
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
    <br><br>
    Web: <input type="text" name="website">
   <br><br>
   Kom: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
   <br><br>
   G:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="w">w
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">m
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <p><a href="#">Export</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked!
How would you get all values (like input and textareas ...)?

Comment: Works on Firefox and Chrome, but does not on IE

Comment: Do you expect me to know you want IE support? Which version of IE did you test this on?

Comment: test it on version IE 11

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` returns the very first element that is selected or null if none (singular). As long as an element is found accessing it's value property works.

`document.getElementsByTyName` returns an array of elements with the provided tag name (plural). An array does not have a property value, so the return value will be `undefined`. In turn, your text file should contain something like "undefined".

To select all textual inputs and to concatenate their values you may use something like:

```
var textInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text], textarea");
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < textInputs.length; i++) { 
  values.push(textInputs[0].value) 
}
console.log(values.toString())
```

Comment: I get it thanks, so how should I change my code to return the array properly

Comment: Depends on what the outcome should be. Do you want to include the value of all (text) inputs or just the very first.

Comment: I want to output the inputs of all (includings input,textareas..:)

Comment: Thanks I mixed your answer with Adam Azad's one, the inly problem is that I cannot get the input type="radios" not properly.

Comment: Works on Firefox and Chrome, but does not on IE

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementsByTagName` will return a list of all your inputs including the radiobuttons and submit button. So you should either iterate through them or select a single element from the array.